# Retrieval of Deleted Build from camelot

Tags: cruisecontrol

After triggering the build on CruiseControl, the build got tagged in one of the directory of camelot server, but then it was accidentally deleted from the filezilla which was connected to camelot remotely.

So could it be possible to get back the deleted build.